# Unable to write-file on google cloud function workspace

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, filesystems

The library I have used is **node-persist** -- [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-persist)

The idea is to save a token in a file using the above library for a particular time period, which can be used while the google cloud function trigger.

But I'm getting below error while saving fresh token in google function workspace.

```
error => [Error: EROFS: read-only file system, unlink '/workspace/tmp/94c8aa2452bccd82ee129b46f7c4be79'] {
     errno: -30,
     code: 'EROFS',
     syscall: 'unlink',
     path: '/workspace/tmp/94c8aa2452bccd82ee129b46f7c4be79'
}
```

**Got the Solution**

Can do file system operation on `/tmp` or `os.tmpdir()`
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-temp-files